# Why i get Generator object at xxxxxx?

Tags: sensors, esp8266, transformer-model, micropython

Hey i wrote this code from the library CT sensor written for micropython, this is the link to the library:

https://github.com/alisonsalmeida/emonlib-micropython

```
from machine import Pin, ADC
import utime
from emonlib import Emonlib
from time import sleep
adc = ADC(0)
ct = Emonlib
ct.current(object, adc, 10)
cd=  ct.calc_current_rms(10,2)
while True:
  
  print(cd)
  sleep(0.5)
```

i can not figure out how to get the value of the current RMS, i am quite new to python,

**Could you help me to learn how to work on that library?**
*i have not found anything yet online, i am trying since weeks :(*

Comment: The obvious error is that `ct = Emonlib` sets `ct` equal to the *class* Emonlib, when what you want to do is *create an instance* of the class: `ct = Emonlib()`

Comment: Hey @nekomatic , thank you so much for your answer and suggestion, i changed the code accordingly: `from machine import Pin, ADC
import utime
from emonlib import Emonlib
from time import sleep
import machine
import time
from math import pow, sqrt


adc = ADC(0) # Initialization ADC
ct = Emonlib() # Initialization Library

ct.current(adc, 10) #Pin, calibration

Irms =  ct.calc_current_rms(1000) # Sample

while True:
  print(Irms)
  sleep(0.5)` But i still have the same problem, the output is: <generatot object 'calc_current_rms' at 3fff0870>

Answer (score 0):

i am lucky to have a friend that helped me.
This should be enough for a starting point

```
from Emonlib import Emonlib
import uasyncio
from machine import Pin

async def main():
    emon = Emonlib() 
    p1 = Pin(1)
    await emon.current(p1,30)
    amps = await emon.calc_current_rms(1480)
    watt = amps * 220
    print(watt)

uasyncio.run(main())
```